# Change permissions using chattr

Tags: unix

How can I change permissions of a directory using chattr? Suppose, I want to change permissions of a directory /path/to/dir to 700 using chattr. Is that possible? If yes then please tell how.

Answer (score 1):

You must use 'chmod' to set permissions to 700:

```
sudo chmod 700 /var/lib/mysql
```

Or if you want to change all subdirectories under /var/lib/mysql

sudo  find /var/lib/mysql -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;

Answer (score 0):

You should use `chmod` instead of `chattr`: the latter has a completely differerent purpose.

Comment: I am root, but when I'm changing permissions of /var/lib/mysql subdirs to 700 but getting OperationNotPermitted error. Can I change with chattr?

Comment: Post the output of `lsattr /var/lib/mysql`.

Comment: @user228046 are you still interested in this question?